# Regex - match anything except specific string

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation

I need a regex (will be used in ZF2 routing, I believe it uses the preg_match of php) that matches anything except a specific string.

For example: I need to match anything except "red", "green" or "blue".

I currently have the regex:

```
^(?!red|green|blue).*$

test -> match (correct)
testred -> match (correct)
red -> doesn't match (correct)
redtest -> doesn't match (incorrect)
```

In the last case, the regex is not behaving like I want. It should match "redtest" because "redtest" is not ("red", "green" or "blue").

Any ideas of how to fix the regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can include the end of string anchor in the lookahead

```
 ^(?!(red|blue|green)$)
```

Comment: This regex is matching nothing. Have you tested it?

Comment: @rafaame yup; matched test, testred, and redtest, but not red http://rubular.com/r/b9eMsVln1W

Comment: @rafaame perhaps try adding `.*` at the end if you need to actually capture the string

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this regex can help you out:

```
^(?!red|green|blue)(.+)|(.+)(?<!red|green|blue)$
```

Check out this at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/KnksVvqF6d).

Answer (score 0):

Regexp like this includes condition of second block - *YOUR_REGEXP*, and exclude condition of first block. In this case if your string will contains *red*, *green* or *blue* result **always** would be **false**

```
'(?si)(?!.*(red|green|blue).*)(.*(YOUR_REGEXP).*)'
```