# Update and sort Qt ComboBoxes alphabetically

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, combobox

I want to write a program, working like a little navigation system uisng the Qt framework, but i still am very new to it.

I created a dialog with two Comboboxes. Each combobox contains all "citynames".
At the initialization the content of both boxes is sorted alphabetically.

If a name in the first box is selected, it should not be displayed in the second one and the other way too.

I successfully removed the item and added it again, if another item is selected, but know i cannot sort them anymore

This is what i tried so far for updating:

```
for(std::vector<City>::iterator iter = citylist.begin(); iter != citylist.end(); iter++){
    if(ui->combo2->currentText() != (*iter).getName()
            and ui->combo1->findText((*iter).getName()) == -1){
        ui->combo1->addItem((*iter).getName(),QComboBox::InsertAlphabetically);
    }
}
```

but it does not insert the items alphabetically...

so i tried to sort it afterwards:

```
 QSortFilterProxyModel* proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(ui->combo1);

proxy->setSourceModel(ui->combo1->model());

// combo's current model must be reparented,
// otherwise QComboBox::setModel() will delete it
ui->combo1->model()->setParent(proxy);

ui->combo1->setModel(proxy);

// sort
ui->combo1->model()->sort(0);
```

But if i try to call this function an error occurs and the application terminates.

So is anyone out there, who is able to help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `QComboBox`'s internal model as source model for `proxy`. This is not going to work because `QComboBox` owns its internal model and when you call `QComboBox::setModel`, previous model is deleted (despite you reset its parent). You need to create a separate source model. Conveniently, you can use one source model for both comboboxes if cities list is the same.

Using `QSortFilterProxyModel` for sorting is easy, but it's surprisingly hard to exclude one specific string with it. You can subclass `QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow` and implement the behavior you want. I decided to use a bit of black magic instead (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16930660/344347)).

Private class fields:

```
private:
  QSortFilterProxyModel *proxy1, *proxy2;
```

Source:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
  foreach(QString name, QStringList()
      << "Paris"<< "London"<< "Moscow" << "Tokyo" << "Berlin" << "Amsterdam") {
    model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(name));
  }

  proxy1 = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
  proxy1->setSourceModel(model);
  proxy1->sort(0);
  ui->comboBox1->setModel(proxy1);

  proxy2 = new QSortFilterProxyModel();
  proxy2->setSourceModel(model);
  proxy2->sort(0);
  ui->comboBox2->setModel(proxy2);

  connect(ui->comboBox1, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged,
          this, &MainWindow::something_changed);
  connect(ui->comboBox2, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged,
          this, &MainWindow::something_changed);

  something_changed();
}

void MainWindow::something_changed() {
  ui->comboBox1->blockSignals(true); //prevent recursion
  ui->comboBox2->blockSignals(true);
  proxy2->setFilterRegExp(QString("^(?!(%1)$)").arg(
                          QRegExp::escape(ui->comboBox1->currentText())));
  proxy1->setFilterRegExp(QString("^(?!(%1)$)").arg(
                          QRegExp::escape(ui->comboBox2->currentText())));

  ui->comboBox1->blockSignals(false);
  ui->comboBox2->blockSignals(false);
}
```

Tested in Qt 5.3.

Answer (score 14):

You were nearly there!

```
ui->comboBox1.addItem("myitem");
// qApp->processEvents();  not really needed
ui->comboBox1.model()->sort(0);
```