# Accept anything except than a specific string in middle with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a "simple" regex to match any string except a specific string in middle. Lets assume that the specific string is `apple`, Here are results that I expect:

```
apple -> false
foo-apple -> false
foo-apple-bar -> false
empty-string -> true
foo -> true
```

I tried:

```
^(?!apple)$
^(?!apple$)
^.*(?!apple).*$
^(.*(?!apple).*)$
```

but none of them worked as I expected. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16930563/3328979) looks similar but the accepted answer is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word. You are looking for `^(?!.*apple)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, That question has 2k+ votes and it never came in my search results :/. Yes that is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your answer surprisingly works while it is different than the accepted answer (accepted answer is `^((?!apple).)*$` ). Is there any question that refer to your answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I think I understood your answer. It just avoid (.*apple) string. It is even simpler than the accepted answer. Thanks.